# Qt Creator doesn't open terminal

Tags: c++, qt

I install Qt Creator 3.5.1 and create project. 
In such case

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

It works but Qt Creator doesn't open terminal and write down "Hello world" in "application output".
When I modify code a little bit

```
int main(void)
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Hello World! %d\n", num);
    return 0;
 }
```

It doesn't work.
"application output" say: Starting /home/project/pr1 .....

The terminal does not open.
In settings I try to change the different terminals

/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x

/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -e

/usr/bin/xterm -e

It does not help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Open Your Project in Qt and Follow the steps given in the picture, Your terminal should run. Check **Run in terminal**

Answer (score 2):

This option can be edited in

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Build and Run
4. General
5. Default for "run in terminal"   =     enabled

Comment: Also use in 
Menu->Tools->Options->[System] (dash dash instead -e)
Terminal /usr/bin/gnome-terminal  [        ]  [--     ]